# How do I transform a pattern on booleans to an if condition?

Tags: haskell, if-statement, boolean

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to transform the pattern matching below to an if condition:

```
myOr :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
myOr False False = False
myOr _     _     = True
```

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't even compile:

```
myOr2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
myOr2 False False = False
myOr2 _     _     = True
myOr2 If False False Then False Else True
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
bool_or x y = if x
              then ...          -- x is true
              else if y
                   then ...     -- y is true
                   else ...     -- both false
```

Pattern matching is much more readable, anyway.

Exercise: you do not really *need* the second `if y`.